# How to divide incoming rows of data to be executed by CodeIgniter's update_batch() and insert_batch()?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord, batch-processing

My objective is to use a combination of CodeIgniter's `insert_batch()` and `update_batch()` to add incoming data to my `macro_plan` table.

In my script below I am attempting to query the database for existing rows based on `sr_no` values then appropriately call the batch querying methods.

```
function insert_batch($dataSet)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("select sr_no from macro_plan");
    $data = $query->result_array();
    $sr_nos=array();

    foreach($data as $key => $value):
        $sr_nos[$key]=$value['sr_no'];
    endforeach;

    $query1= $this->db->query("select * from macro_plan WHERE sr_no IN ('".$sr_nos."')");
    $update_query = $query1->result();
    if ($update_query->num_rows() > 0) {

        $this->db->update_batch($dataSet,$this->macro_plan);//update if ids exist
    } else {
        $this->db->insert_batch($dataSet,$this->macro_plan);//insert if does not exist
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the "array to string conversion" error.

`$dataset` will resemble this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [quantity_update] => 88
        [sr_no] => 2020-11-1
        [batch] => Batch 2
        [quantity_date_update] => 05-May-20
        [inq_id] => 49
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [quantity_update] => 99
        [sr_no] => 2020-11-2
        [batch] => Batch 1
        [quantity_date_update] => 11-May-20
        [inq_id] => 49
    )
)
```

My table structure looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Which line is 52?

Comment: $query1= $this->db->query("select * from macro_plan WHERE sr_no IN ('".$sr_nos."')");

Comment: How do you identify unique-ness in your table?  is `sr_no` enough by itself, or do you need to use a composite key (`sr_no` AND `batch`)?  How many rows of data do you anticipate having in `$dataSet`?

Comment: Yes, sr_no is enough to find the uniqueness. Rows count may differ, somewhere around 40 - 50.

Comment: sometimes less than 10 - max of somewhere around 40 -50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Query your table for pre-existing rows that contain the `sr_no` values that exist in your `$dataSet`.
2. Then apply keys to the result set rows from the `sr_no` values -- this allows the swift lookup on new data against the old data (to see if the respective new rows should be inserted, executed as an update, or completely ignored because the data is the same.

Untested Suggestion:

```
function insertUpdateMacroPlan($dataSet)
{
    $keyedExistingRows = array_column(
        $this->db
            ->where_in('sr_no', array_column($dataSet, 'sr_no'))
            ->get('macro_plan')
            ->result_array(),
        null,
        'sr_no'
    );

    foreach ($dataSet as $data) {
        if (isset($keyedExistingRows[$data['sr_no']])) {
            // sr_no exists in the db, add known id to new data array
            $identified = ['id' => $keyedExistingRows[$data['sr_no']]['id']] + $data;

            if ($identified != $keyedExistingRows[$data['sr_no']]) {
                $updateBatch[] = $identified;
            }
            // if the arrays contain the same data, the new data will be discarded
        } else {
            $insertBatch[] = $data;
        }
    }

    if (!empty($insertBatch)) {
        $this->db->insert_batch('macro_plan', $insertBatch);
    }
    if (!empty($updateBatch)) {
        $this->db->update_batch('macro_plan', $updateBatch, 'id');
    }
}
```

p.s. if your business logic requires that `sr_no` values are unique, I recommend that you reflect that in your table configuration by setting the `sr_no` column as a Unique Key.

Comment: I never had any idea what `$this->macro_plan` was or why you were using it.  I should have just written what I thought was correct.  Please see my update. (and please delete old comments)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It's working. I'll test with some more scenarios.Thanks again.